# Connecting databases(Mysql) with fusion Chart

Tags: php, mysql, fusioncharts

I am running PHP Version 5.5.24, i have also included the "fusionchart.php" in the project folder too. When i googled for solution , the browser shows the "did not match any document"

```
<?php

   include("fusioncharts.php");



   $hostdb = "localhost";  // MySQl host
   $userdb = "root";  // MySQL username
   $passdb = "suba sah 16";  // MySQL password
   $namedb = "world";  // MySQL database name


      $dbhandle = new mysqli($hostdb, $userdb, $passdb, $namedb,'0','/opt/lampp/var/mysql/mysql.sock');


   if ($dbhandle->connect_error) {
    exit("There was an error with your connection: ".$dbhandle->connect_error);
   }
?>
```

Error:

When i run the code above , i shows the error as follows..
    query($strQuery) or exit("Error code ({$dbhandle->errno}):     {$dbhandle->error}"); ?>

Your help will be appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I tried to run the above code in my localhost, but couldn't find the error mentioned by you. The code is working error free.
If you have missed something, **I would like to know what did you missed out**.

You can even see whether the database connectivity done is correctly done or not.